# SSIS For Loop Container using a date variable for tables

Tags: date, for-loop, ssis

I am trying to automate an SSIS package as in the current format it is using the data from tables from the past three years.

The layout of the table names is TableName_YYYYMM for 2 of them and TableName_YYYYjan or feb etc for the other.

How would I set out the for loop with a date variable so that the package is getting the data from the tables from 3 years ago for each month until the current month?

I am fairly new at SSIS so I have been unable to find any solution yet as I am not 100% sure on how I would go about implementing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say, for me at least, without seeing the details of what you're doing.
While you're building out dates, you're also not as you're only working with year and month so using a date data type probably isn't going to help.

## Create 5 SSIS variables

- Year - Int32 - 0
- Month - Int32 - 0
- YYYYMM - String -  Evaluate as Expression `(DT_WSTR, 4) @[User::Year] + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2) @[User::Month], 2)`
- YYYYMonth - String - Evaluate as Expression `(DT_WSTR, 4) @[User::Year] + @[User::MonthAbr]`
- MonthAbr - String - Evaluate as Expression

Expression

```
(@[User::Month] == 1) ? "Jan" : 
(@[User::Month] == 2) ? "Feb" : 
(@[User::Month] == 3) ? "Mar" : 
(@[User::Month] == 4) ? "Apr" : 
(@[User::Month] == 5) ? "May" : 
(@[User::Month] == 6) ? "Jun" : 
(@[User::Month] == 7) ? "Jul" : 
(@[User::Month] == 8) ? "Aug" : 
(@[User::Month] == 9) ? "Sep" : 
(@[User::Month] == 10) ? "Oct" : 
(@[User::Month] == 11) ? "Nov" : 
(@[User::Month] == 12) ? "Dec" : "UNK"
```

At this point, if I change the value of `Year` or `Month`, those three variable change so that simplifies our problem to "how do we change those two?"

If I have whole year boundaries to work with i.e. 2000 to 2021 Jan to Dec every year, I'd use something like this package. A nested set of For Loop Containers. Outer enumerates years from 2000 to 2021. The inner enumerates 1 to 12. The Sequence Container inside is where I do the actual work. In this case, I simply print the value of my user variables to show it works.

[image]

## For Loop - Year

Configuring the variable `@[User::Year]`

[image]

## For Loop - Month

Configuring the variable `@[User::Month]`

[image]

My Script Task is my much beloved (by me at least) [Test for Echo](https://billfellows.blogspot.com/2016/04/biml-script-task-test-for-echo.html)
Add a Script Task, language is C#. Select the User scoped variables we defined above as ReadOnly variables and use the following in the guts of the script

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ST_EchoBack
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        public void Main()
        {
            bool fireAgain = false;
            string message = "{0}::{1} : {2}";
            foreach (var item in Dts.Variables)
            {
                Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "SCR Echo Back", string.Format(message, item.Namespace, item.Name, item.Value), string.Empty, 0, ref fireAgain);
            }

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }

        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
    }
}
```

## F5

At this point, if you run what I've shown, you'll get Output like the following

```
SSIS package "C:\Users\bfellows\source\repos\SO_Trash\SO_Trash\SO_74444363.dtsx" starting.
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo back, SCR Echo Back: User::Month->1
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo back, SCR Echo Back: User::MonthAbr->Jan
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo back, SCR Echo Back: User::Year->2000
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo back, SCR Echo Back: User::YYYYMM->200001
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo back, SCR Echo Back: User::YYYYMonth->2000Jan
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo back, SCR Echo Back: User::Month->2
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo back, SCR Echo Back: User::MonthAbr->Feb
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo back, SCR Echo Back: User::Year->2000
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo back, SCR Echo Back: User::YYYYMM->200002
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo back, SCR Echo Back: User::YYYYMonth->2000Feb
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo back, SCR Echo Back: User::Month->3
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo back, SCR Echo Back: User::MonthAbr->Mar
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo back, SCR Echo Back: User::Year->2000
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo back, SCR Echo Back: User::YYYYMM->200003
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo back, SCR Echo Back: User::YYYYMonth->2000Mar
```

I like this approach to building packages as it's small, testable and non-destructive. We can confirm out looping and all this nonsense is working before we start lifting and shifting data.

## What if I need to work with a partial year?

Fantastic question. I would add a sixth variable to the mix. Call this one something like `IsValid` and type of boolean. The idea is that you'll add in logic to handle the partial boundary condition. Let's assume we want to load the year 2022 but only through October (10). After adjusting the `EvalExpression` in `FLC Year Enum` to 2023, we'll use the following expression

```
(@[User::Year] == 2022 &&  @[User::Month] > 10) ? False : True
```

If the year is 2022 and the month is greater than 10, then False. All other combinations will yield True. I felt that was more concise than other forms of the test. If you run it now, you'd see the value of IsValid is True until we get to the last two loops of our run. Perfect!

You could either user a Precedent Constraint or set the Disable property on the  SEQC Do Work.

### Precedence Constraint approach

[image]

Inside the Sequence Container between the first task (an empty Sequence Container is an excellent anchor as it is a logical construction and requires no configuration) and the second task and set the Evaluation operation as Expression and Constraint. Value is Success. Expression is `@[User::IsValid]`

[image]

### Disable approach

The thought here is that we'll set the Disable property of `SEQC Do Work` via Expression. I find this a little confusing from a maintenance perspective as we need to work with the inverse of IsValid because we only want to Disable when it's not valid.

1. Right click on SEQC Do Work
2. Properties
3. Expressions
4. Select Disable -> `!@[User::IsValid]`
5. Ok
6. Ok

[image]

## Do I need to create all these variables

Yes. You might even want some more. Anything that has an expression on it cannot be debugged except through observation of the computed result. I can't put a break point between `(DT_WSTR, 4) @[User::Year]` and `+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2) @[User::Month], 2)` to see whether I'm building out a 2 character month "number." The only thing I can do is look at the value of a variable. Which means, do not use anything in a Task or Containers expression that is not a single Variable. I do violate it above with Disable and that's why I also note it as a maintenance overhead/technical debt.

If I get any weird behaviour while I'm testing this, I can set a breakpoint immediately before the weird task/container and inspect my variables and trace back to why it's weird. If I had the same expression from YYYYMonth but all in a single go attached to an OLE DB Source, good luck trying to figure out why it's pulling incorrect data.

## How can I make the boundaries dynamic?

Add a pair of Variables

- YearInitial - Int32 - 2000
- YearTerminal - Int32 - Evaluate as expression `YEAR(@[System::StartTime])`

[image]

Comment: If I was to want the code to be dynamic so that I wouldn't have to constantly update the year and month that it would run to, could I set in the Year Enum For Loop for the EvalExpression @[User::Year] <= @[User::CurrentYear] if I created a new variable with a GETDATE for the current year?

Comment: @JackNobile Bingo! You can reference other variables within the Expressions so you could use the updated example. For a YearInitial, you could pull from a database value, use a run-time parameter, etc, etc. Possibilities are limited purely to your imagination

Comment: Hopefully my last question. Is there a way so that I can start the loop with the month equalling then current month and finish when the year and month are equal to the current year and month? I’ve tried but the loop just runs from Jan for the first year till Dec on the last year instead of Nov for the first year to Nov of the last year or whatever month it would be that the script is being run?

Comment: Help me understand what the start/stop dates would be. I want to loop from November of 2022 to October of 2029, something like that

Comment: The start/stop dates would be dynamic. For example, this month it would be Nov 2019- Nov 2022, next month it would be Dec 2019 - Dec 2022 and so on. Any data in the tables that are more than 3 years old are not needed

Comment: Update: I was able to get it working. I used the logic behind the IsValid variable to make an IsStartDate and IsEndDate variable and used both variables in the precedence constraint. Thank you for all your help!